# The purpose of PSU & motherboard -12V line

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, voltage

Typically PSUs have -12V line rated about 0.2 - 0.5A. But for what is it used?
Is it used for example with one of the +12V lines to get total 24V?
What component or so needs that -12V or possibly 24V?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, it seems -12V is mainly still there because it's part of the [ATX specifications](https://xdevs.com/doc/Standards/ATX/ATX12V_Power_Supply_Design_Guide_Rev1.1.pdf) and for backward compatibility.

Also see this question on electronics StackExchange: [What is the use of negative voltages on a PC motherboard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105064/what-is-the-usage-of-the-negative-voltages-on-a-pc-motherboard).

-12V used to be necessary for Serial Port voltages (RS232) and was also part of the original PCI bus specifications.

Comment: Thanks. [Related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/105076/162291)